# GCRS and ICRS Frame in Optical Observations from near earth

Tags: observation, optical, frames

Lets say I am trying to observe the night sky. My telescope has a pointing direction. I want to compare the RADecs of each star with another. Now I have 4 cases.

1. My telescope is on a satellite orbiting earth and I am trying to observe the sky. I define the pointing direction in ICRF. And compute the RADecs of the stars based on pointing direction RADecs in ICRF.
2. My telescope is on a satellite orbiting earth and I am trying to observe the sky. I define the pointing direction in GCRF. And compute the RADecs of the stars based on pointing direction RADecs in GCRF.
3. My telescope is on ground and I am trying to observe the sky. I define the pointing direction in ICRF. And compute the RADecs of the stars based on pointing direction RADecs in ICRF.
4. My telescope is on ground and I am trying to observe the sky. I define the pointing direction in GCRF. And compute the RADecs of the stars based on pointing direction RADecs in GCRF.

As I understand, in both scenarios (telescope on ground or orbit), I should get more accurate results when pointing is defined in GCRF frame as it takes care of the aberrations (added due to relativity theory).

However, in a few examples I see observations for earth orbiting objects in RADecs in just ICRF. Which seems to defeat the purpose of having GCRF.

If anyone has some clarity on the topic, please help me understand this. Thankyou.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Might you get a better chance of an answer at the Astronomy stack?

Comment: If you want to find the RA Dec of something, generally you compare it to nearby defining sources like the GAIA catalog.  With the expectation that all objects in the field of view will have similar distortions (abberation, lens distortion, atmospheric refraction, etc).